# jQuery enable/disable asp.net controls based on user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, markup, client-side

I am generating following recurring markup from asp.net -

```
        <tr id="trRow0" class="trClass">
            <td id="cell0" class="tdClass">
                <input id="MainContent_rptColleges_rbCollege_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rptColleges$ctl01$rbCollege" value="mit" />
                mit
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input id="MainContent_rptColleges_rptCourses_0_rbCourse_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rptColleges$ctl01$rptCourses$ctl01$rbCourse" value="computer science" />
                        &nbsp; computer science
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input id="MainContent_rptColleges_rptCourses_0_rbCourse_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rptColleges$ctl01$rptCourses$ctl02$rbCourse" value="mechanical engg." />
                        &nbsp; mechanical engg.
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="trRow1" class="trClass">
            <td id="cell1" class="tdClass">
        **...
        ...**
```

Once the user clicks on any row college radio button, containing child radio button has to be enabled. Upon selecting other row, previously selected child radio buttons should be reset/disabled.

I have achieved half success using jQuery, by obtaining selected row TR ID with following code,

```
    $(document).ready(function myfunction() {            
        $('[id*=rbCollege]').click(function (e) {
            var selectedCollegeRow = jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
            $(selectedCollegeRow).find('input[name$=rbCourse]'). //code to enable disable radio
        });
    });
```

What other info am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `disabled` attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function myfunction() {            
    $('[id*=rbCollege]').click(function (e) {
        var selectedCollegeRow = jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
        $(selectedCollegeRow).find('input[name$=rbCourse]').attr('disabled', 'true');
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but here my goal is to enable course selection for current row, and disable for others,  attr('disabled', 'true') will not do the needful.